# How to get custom attribute value in multi store config

Tags: php, product-attribute, multistore

in one shop config I use to get attr value

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$att_value = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMyattribute();
```

but on multi store config its not work. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
              ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
              ->load($_product->getId());
$value = $_product->getMyAttribute();
```